# Dynamic property interception

Tags: c#, dynamic, properties, castle-dynamicproxy

I have classes with properties implemented in dll (I can not change implementation because i do not have huge source code). I can not replace using of property `Name` with inherited class because project have thousands lines of code where it used(Ctrl+h does not help). Somebody told that my problem can be solved by Dynamic property interception across Castle and Unity. But i cannot find any workable small examples. Can you show how to implement it? I read that Castle dynamic proxy intercepts only virtual methods. Is it possible to intercepts non virtual methods with interface?

```
namespace DynamicInterception
{
    // Placed int first dll
    public class Cargo
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    //Placed in second dll
    public class Wagon
    {
        public Cargo Cargo { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Wagon wagon = new Wagon();
            wagon.Cargo = new Cargo() { Name = "Test" };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i think you can create like that new {prop1="value", prop2="value2"};

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with Castle Dynamic Proxy you can intercept non-virtual members of a class if the member is part of an interface.  Look at the [documentation](https://github.com/castleproject/Core/blob/master/docs/dynamicproxy.md) (specifically the section on `IInterceptor`) and if you're having problems, start a new question with some sample code showing the issue you're having.